# Why can't the compiler find the superclass's method?

Tags: c++, methods, abstract-class, superclass, subclassing

I'm trying to do class inheritance in C++, but it obviously works very differently than in Python.

Right now, I have two classes, one called `Player` that is the base class, and another one called `HumanPlayer` that's the subclass.

The `Player` class is an abstract class that has two ways of working.

The first is that it acts like a singleton. It has one static function called `make_move` that people can call with an `int` and a `TicTacToeGame&`, and it will make a move for the player with that `int` as the player's number in that game of `TicTacToe`.

The second is that it works as a class for creating objects that have a player number as a property. So, if you construct an object with the class, you should get back an object with a `player_number` property. Then, if you call the `make_move` function with just a `TicTacToeGame&` on the object, it will automatically plug in its player number and use the static class method to make the move in the game.

I want the same functionality for `HumanPlayer`, except I just want to have to write a new static function for `HumanPlayer`, and that's it, since the other functionality remains the same.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class TicTacToeGame {

};

class Player {
    public:
        static void make_move(int player_number, TicTacToeGame& game);

    protected:
        int player_number;

    public:
        explicit Player(int player_number_param) {
            player_number = player_number_param;
        }

    public:
        void make_move(TicTacToeGame& game) {
            return make_move(player_number, game);
        }
};

class HumanPlayer: public Player {
    public:
        static void make_move(int player_number, TicTacToeGame& game) {}

    public:
        HumanPlayer(int player_number_param): Player(player_number_param) {}
};

int main()
{
    TicTacToeGame game;
    HumanPlayer human_player = HumanPlayer(2);
    human_player.make_move(game);
    return 0;
}
```

I learned recently that subclasses don't inherit constructors, so it turns out I have to write both a new static function and a constructor, which I have done.
However, whenever I initialize a new `HumanPlayer` object, the compiler can't seem to find a match for the `make_move(TicTacToeGame&)` method, and I'm not sure why.

The specific error message I'm getting is

> C:\Users\London\Desktop\Python
>   Programs\LearningC++\FirstProgram_SO.cpp: In function 'int main()': 
>   C:\Users\London\Desktop\Python
>   Programs\LearningC++\FirstProgram_SO.cpp:41:29: error: no matching
>   function for call to 'HumanPlayer::make_move(TicTacToeGame&)' 
>   human_player.make_move(game);  ^  C:\Users\London\Desktop\Python
>   Programs\LearningC++\FirstProgram_SO.cpp:29:15: note: candidate:
>   static void HumanPlayer::make_move(int, TicTacToeGame&)  static void
>   make_move(int player_number, TicTacToeGame& game) {}  ^~~~~ 
>   C:\Users\London\Desktop\Python
>   Programs\LearningC++\FirstProgram_SO.cpp:29:15: note: candidate
>   expects 2 arguments, 1 provided

How can I get the `HumanPlayer` class to work in the same way the `Player` class does?

Comment: Also, the `Player` class compiles fine if I add in an empty definition for its static `make_move` method. I can create an object with it and do `obj.make_move(game)` and it compiles. However, with `HumanPlayer`, that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Where is the int? You're supposed to pass a int as first parameter. Edit: Ah you want the parents non-static `make_move` to be called?

Comment: The `HumanPlayer` should inherit the `make_move(TicTacToe&)` method from the `Player` class. The `make_move(TicTacToe&)` method then calls the static `make_move(int, TicTacToe&)` method, using the protected variable `player_number` as the `int`.

Comment: @tkausl precisely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The redefinition of the static function with the same name is hiding the one you want to use.

Either rename it differently or add

```
public:
    using Player::make_move;
```

Note that unlike Java you don't need to repeat `public:` before every function, the same visibility applies as long as you don't change it.

```
class YourClass {
public:
    void foo1(); // public
    void bar1(); // also public
protected:
    void foo2(); // protected
    void bar2(); // also protected
};
```

Comment: How can I tell if a function will hide the one I want to use? I had assumed that having different parameter types would cause it to not hide.

Comment: @ProQ Overload resolution is only done after determining which class defines the name.

Comment: In other words, redefining a function in a derived class replaces all overloads, not just the ones with the same parameter types.

Comment: If I add `using Player::make_move;` it complains because `Player` is just an abstract class, so it doesn't have a definition for `make_move(int,  TicTacToe&)`. Is there any easy way to get around this? Do I include `using Player::make_move;` *after* I define the static function in `HumanPlayer`?

Comment: @ProQ You can't leave the static function unimplemented. A class is made abstract by providing (at least one) pure virtual member functions.

Comment: Ah, so I think I'm now running into issues more along the lines of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313754/static-abstract-methods-in-c). I'll do more research.

Comment: @ProQ No. You're looking for [Non-Virtual interface idiom](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Non-Virtual_Interface).

Comment: I don't see any static functions in the Non-Virtual interface idiom. How would I convert my current classes into something that uses that format?

Comment: @ProQ Turn your static function into the virtual one.

Comment: In my case, that takes away the point of there being a static version that can be called without an object being created. I think I'm better off just not using a `Player` class at all.