# How to override static method of template class in derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, static

I'm having a little issue with overriding static methods of base clases, but the whole question is very complicated and too long (generalization of resource management in game engine), so here's a simplified version:

```
template<class T>
class base
{
    static void bar()
    { printf("bar"); }
public:
    static void foo()
    { bar(); }
};

class derived : public base<int>
{
    static void bar()
    { printf("baz"); }
};

int main() { derived::foo(); }
```

The code above outputs "bar" in my case, insted I want it to output "baz". How can I go about that? It seems that no matter what I attempt, base::foo() always calls base::bar(). I might have an issue with the design. I've never came across this problem - how can I resolve it?

Comment: You can't override static methods. You can overload them (which is what you're doing here), but you're just getting static dispatch. I guess you could use the [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternative to c++ static virtual methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721846/alternative-to-c-static-virtual-methods)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

What you're trying to do is not achievable with simple class inheritance; a method cannot be both `static` and `virtual`.

You need a `static` method to be able to call a function without an object (an instance); and you need `bar` to be `virtual` so that `bar<int>::foo()` calls `derived::bar()` when called from a `derived` *instance*.

Those two traits are mutually exclusive. But the [Curiously Recursive Template Pattern (CRTP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) may be a solution here:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
struct base
{
    static void foo()
    {
        T::bar();
    }
};

struct derived : public base<derived>
{
    static void bar()
    {
        std::cout << "derived" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    derived::foo();
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/afdb9c8f6cef344a)

Comment: Thank you very much!
Your answer helped me!

Comment: This answer blew my mind. How does the complier know that there will be a method bar() on class T? Does it statically check every instance of base<T> to make sure it fits the usage?

Comment: @MayaNedeljkovich It doesn't. Anytime a specialization of `base<T>::foo` is made (in the example program, the exact time `base<derived>::foo` is called), it _does_ check that `base<T>::foo` make sense for the given `T`. This is the so-called template second pass compilation (aka "in deduced context"). If it was not the case, => compilation error. [Try it by yourself](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4468b8dcdd5d54c7).

Comment: @YSC: +1 for providing live examples two times!

Comment: @MayaNedeljkovich Typically in rust we can use the trait bound on the template arguments. In cpp20, there seems a similar concept named "concept", I'm not a master of C++ template, but I think the <trait> stdlib could help before cpp20.