# Can g_time_out add be given a member function of a class?

Tags: c++, gtk, gtk2

The question is simply in the title, if I have a function I want to use via a `g_timeout_add()`, but this function is a class member function, is there any way I can use it with `g_timeout_add()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a trampoline function, e.g.:

```
extern "C" gboolean trampoline(gpointer data) {
    static_cast<MyClass*>(data)->mem_fun();
}

// ...
MyClass c = /* ... */;
g_timeout_add(/*...*/, static_cast<gpointer>(&c));
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068022/in-c-is-it-safe-portable-to-use-static-member-function-pointer-for-c-api-callb) on why you should use free functions if you want to write portable code.