# C++ pthread_create Parameter

Tags: c++

I was previously using a `void*` function as the third parameter of `pthread_create`, and here is what it looked like:

```
void* nameChange(void*){ ... }
...
pthread_t id;
pthread_create(&id, NULL, nameChange, NULL);
```

This worked. But I have made some changes to my code and need the function `nameChange` to be a member of my class `MainWindow`. Here's the only difference now:

```
void* MainWindow::nameChange(void*)
```

Now, I get an error when putting `nameChange` as the parameter. Here's what it says:

`error: cannot convert 'MainWindow::nameChange' from type 'void* (MainWindow::)(void*)' to type 'void* (*)(void*)'`

What is it that I am doing wrong here? I'm pretty new to threads, so any help is appreciated!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/26430129/12711

Comment: Thanks. This along with @zangw's answer make things clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between a C function and a C++ member function is that C function uses *cdecl* calling convention, while member functions uses *thiscall* calling convention. You can't call the member function directly. **Member function pointers are not the same type as function pointers**.

Maybe here is one workaround

```
void* callback(void*)
{
    MainWindow instance;
    instance.nameChange();
}

pthread_create(&id, NULL, callback, NULL);
```