# Accessing non static members inside static method via passed pointer

Tags: c++, multithreading, static, this

Not the actual code, but a representation:

I need to initiate a thread from one of my member functions and I do that this way:

```
return_val = pthread_create(&myThread, NULL, myStaticMethod, (void*)(this));
```

i) I pass **this** as an argument because static methods do not allow non-static members to be accessed, and since I have non-static methods and members to access inside the static method. **Is this right? Or, are there any other alternatives?**

```
myStaticMethod(void* args)    
{
    args->myPublicMethod(); //Is this legal and valid?

    args->myPrivateMember;   //Is this legal and valid?
}
```

I get an error saying **void* is not a pointer to object type**, and I think that **args is  to be typecast into an instance of type myClass**.

But, how do I do that?

Comment: Note that it is not a good idea to pass C++ static functions to C, see [that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068022/in-c-is-it-safe-portable-to-use-static-member-function-pointer-for-c-api-call) for example. Better to create an `extern "C"` wrapper around it. And use `reinterpret_cast` for that kind of casts.

Comment: @SergeyTachenov: I did go though that before actually posting the question. But, certain 'external forces' do  prevent you from doing the right thing by sticking to what is normally, but incorrectly followed.

Comment: What on Earth could prevent you from writing a simple small `extern "C"` wrapper around a static member function? Just name it accordinly, like `MyClass_myStaticMethod()` to avoid name clashes.

Comment: This discussion is nonsense considering that C++ has its own threads that perfectly well interoperate with any function. Also, the correct cast is surely not `reinterpret_cast` when converting a `T*` to a `void*` and back, but `static_cast`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
args->myPublicMethod(); //Is this legal and valid?
```

No. That is neither legal nor valid. However, you can use:

```
reinterpret_cast<MyClass*>(args)->myPublicMethod();
```

You can access a `private` member function of a class from a `static` member function. So, you can access a `private` member of the class using:

```
reinterpret_cast<MyClass*>(args)->myPrivateMember;
```

[Another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573294/when-to-use-reinterpret-cast) and its answers discuss the pros and cons of using `static_cast` and `reinterpret_cast`. Since you are using `void*` as the intermediate type, you can use either of them.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance. Is the **reinterrpet_cast** really required?

Comment: No, the `reinterpret_cast` could actually be wrong. Use a `static_cast`. Actually, forget that and use `std::thread`.